# Counting the number of row but nothing is printed to the console?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to count the row in a table `supplierNum` to find out how many supplies each supplier has

The created table code is:

```
CREATE TABLE supplier 
(
    supplierNum CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    name CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    status TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (supplierNum)
);
```

The syntax I am using to execute the query is

```
String query = "SELECT city, COUNT(supplierNum) AS suplierCnt "+
                "FROM supplier "+
                "GROUP BY city "+
                "ORDER BY city DESC";
```

It works using MySQL work bench, when I execute it in eclipse it just shows a blank terminal with no error message, which makes me think that it is something I am missing in the code?

The full code I am using in the `try` block is

```
    try{
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        System.out.println("Connected");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();

        String query = "SELECT city, COUNT(supplierNum) AS suplierCnt "+
                        "FROM supplier "+
                        "GROUP BY city "+
                        "ORDER BY city DESC";

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);  

        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("supplierCnt"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("city"));
            space();
        }
    }
```

The expected result would look like this

[image]

Comment: There's a `try {` statement in your code. Does it have a `catch(`? Can you post it here? It's possible that it silently swallows the exception and, thus,  prevents you from debugging.

Comment: Also, if you have a blank terminal, it means that this code is not executed at all, or that `DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);`throws an exception. Otherwise you would see "Connected" in the terminal. Use your debugger. Don't ignore exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
System.out.println(rs.getInt("supplierCnt"));
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(rs.getString("supplierCnt"));
```

As count() returns int. This might help you.

Comment: @ Gaurav Dhiman: Thanks I knew it was something I was missing I am new to this and was watching videos on metaData, BLOB ..... you helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
 System.out.println(rs.getString("supplierCnt"));
```

This block of code refers to a different string than

```
SELECT city, COUNT(supplierNum) AS suplierCnt "+
```

Note here that the column names don't match.